# extract the content of a html tag with all tags inside from beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract the content of a tag without this tag itself and keeping all the tags inside.

```
html_text = "<TD WIDTH=60%>Portsmouth - Cherbourg<BR/>Portsmouth - Santander<BR/></TD>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
soup_list = soup.find_all("td")
soup_object = soup_list[0]
text = soup_object.getText()
print(soup_object)
```

I get:

> <td width="60%">Portsmouth - Cherbourg<br/>Portsmouth - Santander<br/></td>

But I want:

> Portsmouth - Cherbourg<br/>Portsmouth - Santander<br/>

Using :

`soup_object.getText()`

... return:

> Portsmouth - CherbourgPortsmouth - Santander

But it is not what I want.

I know I can get the full content of the tag from a regex:

```
re.search("<td.?>(.)</td>", str(soup_object)).group(1)
```

... but I use BeautifulSoup so I don't have to type this kind of code.

A last thing:

```
soup_object.contents
```

... does not return what i want:

> ['Portsmouth - Cherbourg', <br/>, 'Portsmouth - Santander', <br/>]

Am I missing out on a Beautifulsoup feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use `decode_contents` as follows

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_text = "<TD WIDTH=60%>Portsmouth - Cherbourg<BR/>Portsmouth - Santander<BR/></TD>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
soup_list = soup.find_all("td")
soup_object = soup_list[0]
inner_html = soup_object.decode_contents()
print(inner_html)
```

output

```
Portsmouth - Cherbourg<br/>Portsmouth - Santander<br/>
```

Comment: I didn't know about `.decode_contents()` before - that's pretty cool!

Answer (score 0):

TIL about `soup.find("td").decode_contents()` method, and that does seem like the simplest and best method, but even before,  there were several ways to get the "innerHTML".

Since you already noticed the `contents`

```py
''.join(soup_object.contents)
```

or, since we know prettify produces a certain format,

```py
'\n'.join(soup_object.prettify().split('\n')[1:-1])
```

although I will admit that this is rather like using regex after all...

---

Btw, `find()` is pretty much the same as `find_all()[0]` - wasn't sure you knew, but I find using just `find()` much more convenient in these situations